# Knockoutjs binding objects issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm studying knockoutjs and having some issues. I have ASP.NET MVC page with a method returning list of three Car objects is JSON. I than map it to `select` in HTML view and I want to display cost of a selected car on selection change. The problem is that a name of a car is visible while a price is not ('A Mercedes-Benz costs .'). What it could be? Thanks in advance!
Controller:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public JsonResult GetCars()
{
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
    cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Mercedes-Benz", Price = 103000 });
    cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Toyota", Price = 37000 });
    cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Huyndai", Price = 17000 });
    return Json(cars, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And View with Javascript code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function Car(data) {
                this.Make = ko.observable(data.Make);
                this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
            }

            function CarsViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                //Data
                self.someOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.myOption = ko.observable();

                //Operations
                self.initData = function () {
                    $.get('/Home/GetCars', function (data) {
                        var mappedCars = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Car(item) });
                        self.someOptions(mappedCars);
                    });
                }
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new CarsViewModel());
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button data-bind="click: initData">Load data</button>
        <h4>Preview</h4>
        <p>
            <select data-bind="options: someOptions, optionsText: 'Make', value: myOption"></select><br />
            A <span data-bind="text: myOption().Make"></span> costs <span data-bind="text: myOption().Price"></span>.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you check your browser's JavaScript console you should see the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function
>   (){return myOption().Make }" Message: Cannot read property 'Make' of
>   undefined

You get this error because when your page is loaded your `myOption` is empty so it does not have a `Make` and `Price` properties. So KO cannot execute the binding `data-bind="text: myOption().Make"` and it stops with the processing of the further bindings.

After calling `initData` now you have something in `myOption` but still all the bindings after the `data-bind="text: myOption().Make"` won't work anymore.

To solve this there are multiple ways like:

- using a default value in myOption
- check for null in your bindings with `data-bind="text: myOption() && myOption().Make"`
- or use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

Here is an example for the `with` binding:

```
<!-- ko with: myOption -->
   A <span data-bind="text: Make"></span> 
   costs <span data-bind="text: Price"></span>.
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsgws/).